# Cannot decipher some encrypted text using CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am encrypting a set of data in the following way:

```js
const dataToEncrypt = `${userId}-${unixTime}`;

const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(dataToEncrypt, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("4v7KVa1U_>()7b[CI4IV+KRy<78h-@z5"), {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});
```

The problem is it won’t decrypt!

I tried in PHP, and with an online AES tool it works: [image: Online AES tool:]

But using CryptoJS:

```js
const data = req.query.data; //data received through express webapp api endpoint

const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, "4v7KVa1U_>()7b[CI4IV+KRy<78h-@z5", {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});
```

It doesn’t work and return nothing. I tried converting the paramaters to either Utf8 or Base64 or whatever, tried displayed the result with toString, still nothing?

Any idea where the problem comes from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *...31 character long random key using symbols...* How do you manage to use 31 characters in the online tool? The online tool gives me an error message if less than 32 characters are entered in the key field for AES-256 (even if the UTF-8 encoding provides 32 bytes): `Length of secret key should be 32 for 256 bits key size`. Post sample data with a **31** character non-productive test key that is accepted by the online tool to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Topaco Actually my bad, it is already 32 characters long and I'll give the key because it actually doesn't matter: 4v7KVa1U_>()7b[CI4IV+KRy<78h-@z5

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the CryptoJS encryption code, the key material is converted into a `WordArray` using the [Utf8 encoder](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders). This conversion is missing in your CryptoJS decryption code.
Instead, you pass the key material as string, which means that CryptoJS uses a key derivation function to derive the actual key, s. [The Cipher Input](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).
This causes the key to differ during encryption and decryption, which is why decryption fails.

If this is fixed, decryption works, as the following sample code shows:

```js
// Encryption
const dataToEncrypt = `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`;
const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    dataToEncrypt, 
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("4v7KVa1U_>()7b[CI4IV+KRy<78h-@z5"), 
    {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        // padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, // default!
    }
);
const data = encryptedData.toString();
console.log("Ciphertext: " + encryptedData);

// Decryption
const decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    data, 
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("4v7KVa1U_>()7b[CI4IV+KRy<78h-@z5"), 
    {
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
          // padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, // default!
    }
);
console.log("Decrypted data: " + decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.2.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Now decryption works just like with the [online tool you are using](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) or with (the more reliable) [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true,false)AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27UTF8%27,%27string%27:%274v7KVa1U_%3E()7b%5BCI4IV%2BKRy%3C78h-@z5%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27ECB%27,%27Raw%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=Yis5cFNELzdWajkxTERGUkp1ZEJVRklCRWdSNS9FT0NrdmFzSG4rdUo1cm1FQ0U3cDZoR2NyWU1CZ09XdytJNA).

---

*Security:*
Note that when using a passphrase, a key derivation function such (as Argon2 or at least PBKDF2) should be used.
Also, ECB is insecure. Use a mode with an IV, preferably authenticated encryption like GCM.

However, authenticated encryption is not supported by CryptoJS. Since CryptoJS is [discontinued](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#discontinued) and no longer maintained, you should consider switching to another library, preferably one that supports authenticated encryption like GCM, such as [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

Comment: For some reason, even with that it wasn’t working. I managed to make it work using the built-in "crypto" module from node. Also yes, in the production version I’m using CBC mode with an IV, which is more secure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AugustinS - You're welcome. Actually, the above code runs in any standard CryptoJS environment. If it does not run in your environment, this points to an environment-specific problem, perhaps an old CryptoJS version (the latest CryptoJS version is 4.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

In a React Native App, I use **react-native-crypto** to encrypt and decrypt, I believe the steps should also be something similar to the following code:.

My functions **cypher** and **decipher** look like the following:

```
import {REACT_APP_HASH_IV, REACT_APP_HASH_KEY} from '@env';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import '../../shim.js';

export const cypher = (message: string) => {
  let key = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(REACT_APP_HASH_KEY, 'utf8')
    .digest();

  let iv = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(REACT_APP_HASH_IV, 'utf8')
    .digest()
    .subarray(0, 16);

  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

  let encrypted =
    cipher.update(message, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');

  return encrypted;
};

export const decipher = (encrypted: string) => {
  let key = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(REACT_APP_HASH_KEY, 'utf8')
    .digest();

  let iv = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(REACT_APP_HASH_IV, 'utf8')
    .digest()
    .subarray(0, 16);

  let decipherValue = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);

  let decrypted =
    decipherValue.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8') +
    decipherValue.final('utf8');

  return decrypted;
};
```